# ScrollViewer does not work inside Canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to use `ScrollViewer` inside `Canvas`, but scrolling does not work.

```
<Page
    x:Class="ScrollViewerInCanvas.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ScrollViewerInCanvas"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Canvas>
      <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="400">
          <TextBlock Text="Just a huge text that will not fit into a single frame"
                     FontSize="100" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
        </StackPanel>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

But if I switch `Canvas` with `Grid` everything works. Is there any way to get `ScrollViewer` work inside `Canvas`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho That actually was minimal example that reproduces my problem. My misunderstanding of how Canvas works was the source of the problem. Your answer to my question is actually exactly what I needed. Please, move your part of the answer where you describe how Canvas works to the "Answers" and I will mark it as answer to my question.

Comment: Okay, done. Note the code example I edited into your question. This is the sort of code example that is expected, to ensure easy comprehension and reproducibility of a question. See [mcve] for more details (including the links at the end of that article).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you included in your post, it does not appear you gave the `ScrollViewer` any reason to need to scroll. A `Canvas` element doesn't constrain its children in any way. So in the `Canvas`, the `ScrollViewer` can be as large as it wants, and so it's going to be big enough to contain its children without scrolling. In a `Grid`, it would be stretched to fit its cell, so if the cell is smaller than the children, it will allow scrolling. Give it a reason to scroll, and it will.

For example, you could make the `ScrollViewer` always be the same dimensions as its `Canvas` parent:

```
<Page
    x:Class="ScrollViewerInCanvas.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ScrollViewerInCanvas"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas1">
      <ScrollViewer Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas1}"
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=canvas1}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="400">
          <TextBlock Text="Just a huge text that will not fit into a single frame"
                     FontSize="100" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
        </StackPanel>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Canvas>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Anything that would constrain the size of the `ScrollViewer` to something smaller than the size of its content would cause the scroll bars to become visible and usable.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!